# 2 strange warnings on build after upgrade from ASP.NET Core 1.x to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, upgrade

I have successfully upgrade 2 web apps and 4 library projects in the same solution from .net core 1 to .net core 2 however I am left with two strange warnings on building one of the web apps that I just can't seem to find a solution to online.

The first is:

```
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview4-004215 depends on Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core (>= 15.1.0-preview-000454-01) but Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.1.0-preview-000454-01 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.1.0-preview-000458-02 was resolved.
```

The second is:

```
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview4-004215 depends on Microsoft.Build (>= 15.1.0-preview-000454-01) but Microsoft.Build 15.1.0-preview-000454-01 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.Build 15.1.0-preview-000458-02 was resolved.
```

Weirdly it doesn't give me a details of which project is triggering these, below is the screenshot from Visual Studio

[image: warning from visual studio]

Any ideas? Googling those warnings returns zero results for me.

Comment: you can try to find this reference in `obj\project.assets.json` file (former `project.lock.json`)

Comment: I have exactly the same error with a solution containing a .Net Core 2.0 project, .Net Standard 2.0 libraries and a UWP project generated by Windows Template Studio. The error is shown when I start the UWP app, but it seems to originate from the .Net Core 2.0 project. I did not have anything like `DotNet.Cli.Utils` in my `project.assets.json` file, but the error went away when I unloaded the .Net Core 2.0 app project.